# When can I solve in closed form this curve fitting problem?

Tags: functions, optimization, least-squares

I have $n$ real values $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and $n$ real values $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$; then I have a function $f(x,\boldsymbol\theta)$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and depending on $m$ parameters $\boldsymbol\theta\in\mathbb{R}^m$.

The curve fitting problem is, given $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$, find $\boldsymbol\theta$ such that:

$\underset{\boldsymbol\theta}{\operatorname{argmin}} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(x_i,\boldsymbol\theta))^2$

I know that, for example, in the case

$f(x,\boldsymbol\theta)=\theta_0+\theta_1\,x$

the problem can be solved in closed form, i.e. $\boldsymbol\theta$ can be found by means of a set of formulae like the following (taken from [Wikipedia page about linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)):

$\overline{x} = \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

$\overline{y} = \tfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$

$\theta_1 = \frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}-\bar{x})(y_{i}-\bar{y}) }{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}-\bar{x})^2 }$

$\theta_0 = \bar{y} - \theta_1\,\bar{x}$

What assumptions about $f$ do I need to make to get the existence of a closed form solution?

And I would like to ask the same above question for this problem too:

$\underset{\boldsymbol\theta}{\operatorname{argmin}} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |y_i-f(x_i,\boldsymbol\theta)|$

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Assumptions

Comment: As long as $f(x,\boldsymbol\theta)$ is linear with respect to $\boldsymbol\theta$, you could get explicit formulas (this is multilinear regression) for the first question.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Do you mean "as long as $f(x,a\,\boldsymbol\theta)=a\,f(x,\boldsymbol\theta)$ and $f(x,\boldsymbol\theta_1+\boldsymbol\theta_2)=f(x,\boldsymbol\theta_1)+f(x,\boldsymbol\theta_2)$" ?

Comment: What I mean is that the derivative of $f(x,\theta)$ with respect to any $\theta$ is independent of all of the $\theta$'s